# Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml]

Tags: spring-mvc, exception, servlets, sessionfactory

I am new to spring mvc and facing this issue with session factory
"Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml]"

I added all required jars to class path but it still exists

here is my  spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd    
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Configuration defining views files -->

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/view/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customer_db?useSSL=false"/>
        <property name="user" value="newuser"/>
        <property name="password" value="newuser"/>

        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="3000"/>

    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.luv2code.springdemo.entity"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.mySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />




</beans>
```

and this is my web.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<web-app>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.mySQLDialect</prop>
```

must be

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
```

Here you reference a class and this is case sensitiv. So `my` must be `My` with uppercase M